# MultiThreading in connecting multiple clients to single server in windows in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I have written programs for both client and server in **C++** that can handle multiple clients. Now the problem is like:

I have started two threads in my main() function of server such that One thread listens (opens) for connection with clients and another thread accepts the connection and sends data to the connected client. Both the threads are running  periodically(that is **continuously**).

Now when I connected client 1 to the server the client 1 receives the information and when at the same time another client 2 connects to the server then client 1 will goes into **waiting state** and the client 2 gets the data. Now when I close the client 2 the server shows me both the clients are disconnected, but the client 1 is running because it is in a infinite loop, and as the threads will run periodically , the server starts listening again and also accepting the connection again. This makes a new connection with client1 and the client 1 is receiving data.

Can anyone help me in eliminating this. I need to send the data **simultaneously** to the number of clients that connect to the server and when any client disconnect that should not effect other clients. A simple server that can handle multiple clients.

**My Server Program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <thread>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")


static int flag = 0;
BOOL bOptVal = FALSE;
WSADATA WsaDat;
SOCKET Socket;  
std:: thread t1,t2,t3;
void client_disconnected(SOCKET Socket);
void startThreads();
void timer_start(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval);
void accept_connection();
void send_message();

void start_server_listening()
{

if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&WsaDat)!=0)
{
    std::cout<<"WSA Initialization failed!\r\n";
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");

}

Socket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);       

if (setsockopt(Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *) &bOptVal, sizeof(bOptVal)) < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if(Socket==INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    std::cout<<"Socket creation failed.\r\n";
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");

}

SOCKADDR_IN serverInf;
serverInf.sin_family=AF_INET;
serverInf.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
serverInf.sin_port=htons(8888);

if(bind(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&serverInf),sizeof(serverInf))==SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    std::cout<<"Unable to bind socket!\r\n";
    WSACleanup();
    //system("PAUSE");

}
else{   
listen(Socket,3);


accept_connection();
    }
}

void accept_connection()
{

    SOCKET TempSock=SOCKET_ERROR;
    while(TempSock==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout<<"\nWaiting for incoming connections\n";
        Sleep(2000);
        TempSock=accept(Socket,NULL,NULL);
    }

    // If iMode!=0, non-blocking mode is enabled.
    u_long iMode=1;
    ioctlsocket(Socket,FIONBIO,&iMode);

    Socket=TempSock;
    std::cout<<"Client connected!\r\n\r\n";
    send_message();
    if(flag==1){
        Sleep(1000);
        //system("PAUSE");
    }
}
void send_message()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        int nError=WSAGetLastError();
        if(nError!=WSAEWOULDBLOCK&&nError!=0)
        {
            flag=1;
            client_disconnected(Socket);
            break;

        }
        else {
        char *szMessage="Welcome to the server!\r\n";
        send(Socket,szMessage,strlen(szMessage),0);
        Sleep(2000);            
        }
    }

}
void client_disconnected(SOCKET Socket)
{
    std::cout<<"Client disconnected!\r\n";

            // Shutdown our socket
            shutdown(Socket,SD_SEND);

            // Close our socket entirely
            closesocket(Socket);

            WSACleanup();

}


int main()
{
    // start a timer that executes threads periodically/continuously
    timer_start(startThreads, 200); //calling timer function
    while(true);
    return 0;

}
void timer_start(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval)
{
    std::thread([func, interval]() { // calling startThreads() function
        while (true)
        {
            func();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
        }
    }).detach();
}
void startThreads()
{
      //starting two threads one starts listening and other accepts connections
      t1 = std::thread(start_server_listening);
      t2 = std:: thread(accept_connection);
      t1.join();
      t2.join();

}
```

**My Client Program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <thread>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") 

void startThreads();
void timer_start(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval);
std:: thread t1;

 void  receiveToClient()
{
    WSADATA WsaDat;
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&WsaDat)!=0)
    {
        std::cout<<"Winsock error - Winsock initialization failed\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");

    }

    // Create our socket

    SOCKET Socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(Socket==INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout<<"Winsock error - Socket creation Failed!\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");

    }

    // Resolve IP address for hostname
    struct hostent *host;
    if((host=gethostbyname("localhost"))==NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to resolve hostname.\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");

    }

    // Setup our socket address structure
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port=htons(8888);
    SockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    // Attempt to connect to server
    if(connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr))!=0)
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to establish connection with server\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");

    }

    // If iMode!=0, non-blocking mode is enabled.
    u_long iMode=1;
    ioctlsocket(Socket,FIONBIO,&iMode);

    // Main loop
    for(;;)
    {
        int nError=WSAGetLastError();
        if(nError!=WSAEWOULDBLOCK&&nError!=0)
                break;
        // Display message from server
        char buffer[1000];
        memset(buffer,0,999);
        int inDataLength=recv(Socket,buffer,1000,0);
        std::cout<<buffer;

        //end client when server is disconnected

        Sleep(2000);
    }

    WSACleanup();


}

int main()
{
    timer_start(startThreads, 200);
    while(true);
    return 0;

}
void timer_start(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval)
{
    std::thread([func, interval]() {
        while (true)
        {
            func();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
        }
    }).detach();
}
void startThreads()
{

    t1 = std::thread(receiveToClient);
    t1.join();
}
```

Comment: The while(true);  loop in main only guarantees that your programs will **never** exit.   For the connection handling I would use a vector protected by a mutex to store each connection, and write a function that could check whether the connection is open and remove it if not.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your code runs a lot of threads. Most of them just waiting and never will finished. Furthermore your Socket object is placed in global space. But It should be local for every thread that work with it. For example you can have a list of connections placed in global space. This list must be accessed from threads inside critical section.